# How do I identify the imput side of a transformer

Tags: transformer

I have this [2.5VA Split-Bobbin Power Transformer 115/230VAC](https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10001&langId=-1&productId=221292&storeId=10001&krypto=vFgRhKXJZKuM8sLfuPRmxv3tw%2BNp1UpMVks4N7ZnwCWWarK7DYVMgw%3D%3D&ddkey=https:StoreCatalogDrillDownView). According to page 3 of the [Data Sheet](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/221292.pdf) (PDF) it looks like there is a line on the "DSW" version on the pin 1-4 side. This seems to correspond to a small step down (maybe 1-2 mm or so) on the top of the physical transformer.

Is it safe to assume that is the identifier for the pin 1-4 side? If not, how do I identify which side is the input and which side is the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimple on the transformer should indeed be the index mark for the 1-4 side.

If you're still nervous, take your DMM and measure winding resistances. The input windings will have much (at least 10x) greater resistance than the output windings.

Answer (score 1):

If you enlarge the photos in the datasheet, you will see that the pin numbers are printed on the coil former, just above the pins.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I should have included that. My 16 yo soon, with good eyes, a bright light & a magnifying glass is seeing no numbers on the plastic frame near the pins or anywhere else.